# Python NDB Entity's Key ID customization

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to send an ID to Android but the ID is maximum 9 characters. When I use the urlsafe and key's ID it's not possible since its length is more than 9 chars.
Do you have any suggestion? This ID will be sent back by Android to retrieve the entity

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use custom strings of up to 9 chars as key IDs for those objects. You'd have to pay special attention to ensure they're **unique** for the entities having either no parent or the same parent.

You *might* also have to ensure they're not just digits, which could be interpreted by GAE as a single integer number (which *might* be considered too small for a key ID, judging by the normal length of the auto-generated numerical key IDs). Not too sure about this one, I didn't try.

Something like this:

```
    entity = EntityModel.get_or_insert('AShortOne')
    logging.info(entity.key.id()) # should show 'AShortOne'
    logging.info(EntityModel.get_by_id('AShortOne')) # should show your entity
```